# Infinity Loop in Tkinter

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

I'm writing a program that will inform me, when my CPU temperature goes over 70 grades. It works fine in terminal, but I would like to open it in Tkinter window. Is there a way for Tkinter to update value in window every loop from infinity loop?

I made it this way, but it stops after one loop.
Is there a way to update the value in window every time without opening new Tkinter window every loop please?

```py
from time import sleep
from gpiozero import CPUTemperature as temp
from gtts import gTTS
import os
from tkinter import *

vessel = ""
directory = '/home/pi/Desktop/Notifications'
files = 'Notifications/70.mp3'

window = Tk()
window.title("CPUの温度モニター")




def round():
    CPUTemperature = temp()
    CPUTemperature = CPUTemperature.temperature
    return CPUTemperature


while True:
    CPUTemp = round()
    if CPUTemp == vessel:
        continue 
    elif CPUTemp != vessel:
        vessel = CPUTemp
        lbl = Label(window, text=vessel)
        lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
        window.mainloop()
        print (vessel)
        if vessel > 70:
            path = os.path.exists(directory)
            if path == False:
                path = os.makedirs(directory)
            if os.path.isfile(files):
                os.system("mpg123 " + files)
                sleep(5)
            else:
                tts = gTTS(text="警告。CPUの温度は70度を超えました", lang='ja')
                tts.save(files)
                os.system("mpg123 " + files)
                sleep(5)
        sleep(5)
```

Comment: `window.mainloop` is not an update function. As the name suggests, it is a loop, so any code afterwards will never be reached. Try using `window.update()` instead

Comment: Read [How do you run your own code alongside Tkinter's event loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459083/how-do-you-run-your-own-code-alongside-tkinters-event-loop)

Comment: If this ran, eventually it would run out of memory and crash because a new `Label` widget is created each iteration of the `while` loop. Existing widgets can be modified by calling their [`configure()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method. You can make that happen automatically by using store the temperature value in a [control variable](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/control-variables.html) and using that to create the `Label` via its `textvariable=` configuration option.